# NodeJs и Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, socket.io, websocket

Есть сервер nginx, на котором крутится сайт. Понадобилось в одном из приложений использовать websockets. Установил на этот же сервер NodeJS, добавил к нему express, socket.io.

Структура каталогов:

```
/-папки
 -php файлы
 -папка socket.io
 -/static/js/node/server.js
```

Файл server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
path = require('path');

var app = express();
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var server = app.listen(1337);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(cookieParser);

io.on('connection', function(client){

    client.on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message)
    });

    client.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('disconnected');
    });

});
```

На клиенте

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var socket = io.connect('x.x.x.x',{port: 1337, 'transports': ['websocket','xhr-polling']});
});    
</script>
```

вместо x.x.x.x - естественно реальный ip

На выходе получаем:
[image]

А в консоли браузера:
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://x.x.x.x/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

Если подключение делать так:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

То в консоли чисто, транспорт идет polling при чем по несколько соединений в секунду и в response мы получаем содержимое папки socket.io

Раньше с сокетами и вообще с nodejs дело не имел, потому мне как-то трудно это дается. Может кто подскажет где и что надо подправить?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

У меня создан простейший чат. Серверный файл server.js находится в корне сайта, все остальные (index.html, client.js, style.css) - в папке chat. Вот отрывок кода, который написан в client.js:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1) {
    socket = io.connect('http://asana:8085', {'transports': ['xhr-polling']});
} else {
    socket = io.connect('http://asana:8085');
}`
```

Так почему же во всех браузерах идёт соединение с сервером при обращении к index.html, а в Chrome не хочет? Когда у меня все файлы лежали в корне сайта - всё было нормально.

Короче, я решил этот вопрос: надо для хрома писать :

```
socket = io.connect('http://asana:8085', {'transports': ['websocket','xhr-polling']});
```